# Difference between mpif90 and mpifort

Tags: mpi, openmpi

What is the difference between these two compilers, mpif90 and mpifort? Both seems to be for Fortran 90 code. Both got installed when I installed openMPI on Linux. Are the usage (compiler options) different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The MPI standard says nothing about the various compiler wrappers, except that "Some MPI
libraries are shipped together with special compilation scripts".

Thus, one needs to consult OpenMPI's documentation:

http://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#mpifort-vs-mpif77-and-mpif90

The gist of it is that modern fortran compilers are better about determining if code should be treated like fortran 2008, fortran 2003, fortran 90, fortran 77, or whatever.  OpenMPI wants folks to just use mpifort, and let the fortran front-end compiler do the work.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. This may be off-topic (I'm still figuring out how to use MPI), is "toolchain" MPI-specific jargon/lingo? I'm trying to understand what it means.

Comment: Toolchain refers to the compiler, assembler, and linker that turn code into an executable

Comment: I edited my answer to clarify 'toolchain'.  Thanks for the feedback.